# $httpProvider interceptor not working when $http is injected into a factory

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I have a service called 'api', registered something like this:

```
angular
  .module('myApp')
  .factory('api', ['$http', function ($http) {
    // do stuff with $http.get() etc here.
  }]);
```

... and $http is being customized like this elsewhere:

```
angular
  .module('myApp')
  .factory('httpInterceptor', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    // do stuff to intercept http requests and auth things here
  }]);

angular
  .module('myApp')
  .config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpInterceptor');
  });
```

The interceptors are working when I directly inject `$http` into a controller, but when I use the `api` service in my controller, the `$http` customizations are not working. Looks like Angular does not add the intercepts by the point it's required by the factory I created.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Can you provide more code of API factory?

Comment: are you using `$http` or `api` service inside the interceptors?

Comment: The interceptor factory is directly pushed into the `$httpProvider.interceptors` @ryeballar, so question doesn't arise.

Comment: @Satpal sure it's nothing much really: http://laravel.io/bin/mY8On

Comment: @ryeballar I tried using `$injector.get('$http')` in the `api` service, but that didn't work out either. I think that's what internally happens anyway.

Comment: are there any errors in the console?

Comment: No, none at all; in fact when I put in a `console.log` in the interceptor, it does not get triggered when I use the `api` service but the console gets messages when the normal angular route changes are happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question was based on a wrong premise. The interceptors are in fact working, I was just using the wrong hook point. Instead of customizing the `responseError` property of the interceptor object, I was trying to intercept errors from the `response` property itself. This is why I thought the interceptors weren't working at all.

This problem does not really exist. The provider's interceptors are working correctly even in a factory.

Comment: This helped me immensely.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make the `httpInterceptor` a variable inside the config instead of making it a factory:

```
angular
  .module('myApp')
  .config(function ($httpProvider) {

    var httpInterceptor = ['$rootScope', 
      function($rootScope) {
        // do stuff to intercept http requests and auth things here
      }
    ];

    $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push(httpInterceptor);
  });
```

Please note that I've also changed `$httpProvider.interceptors` to `$httpProvider.responseInterceptors` and the parameter passed to `push()` is not a string.

Let me know if that helps.

**EDIT:**

You can also consider using this plugin: https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth. It has this cool feature after the interception: **"The authService will then retry all the requests previously failed due to HTTP 401 response."**

Comment: Hey, `$httpProviders.responseInterceptors` is `undefined`, so I cannot push anything there. I also tried just making the interceptor function a variable instead of a factory but that didn't work either, I think this is a deeper issue with how factories are instantiated...

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the Github code! Basically I needed to use the [responseError](https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth/blob/master/src/http-auth-interceptor.js#L48) property, and I was trying to catch the errors in the response property itself. Another case of RTFM as usual :D Can you update your answer so I can accept it?